# detect grid view in edit mode at row data bound

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just want to detect that grid view in row editing mode and i just want to bind drop down list at this moment. i found many article and i make this code

I have this error

> DataBinding: 'AllProjects_Result' does not contain a property with
>   the name 'Projects'.

```
  protected void GVAllProjects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlDistrictName = null;
    DropDownList ddlPurposeName = null;
    DropDownList ddlTypes = null;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {

        ddlDistrictName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDistrictName") as DropDownList;
        ddlPurposeName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlPurposeName") as DropDownList;
        ddlTypes = e.Row.FindControl("ddlTypes") as DropDownList;
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        ddlDistrictName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDistrictName") as DropDownList;
        ddlPurposeName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlPurposeName") as DropDownList;
        ddlTypes = e.Row.FindControl("ddlTypes") as DropDownList;
    }
    if (ddlDistrictName != null)
    {
        using (AlamaarRealEstateEntities context = new AlamaarRealEstateEntities())
        {
            ddlDistrictName.DataSource = context.Districts.ToList();
            ddlDistrictName.DataTextField = "DistrictName";
            ddlDistrictName.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlDistrictName.DataBind();

            ddlPurposeName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));
            ddlPurposeName.DataSource = context.Purposes.ToList();
            ddlPurposeName.DataTextField = "PurposeName";
            ddlPurposeName.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlPurposeName.DataBind();

            ddlTypes.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));

            ddlTypes.DataSource = context.Types.ToList();
            ddlTypes.DataTextField = "TypeName";
            ddlTypes.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlTypes.DataBind();

        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {

            ddlDistrictName.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DistrictID")).ToString();
            ddlPurposeName.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PurposeID")).ToString(); 
            ddlTypes.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TypeID")).ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

the error here at those lines:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
{
        ddlDistrictName.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DistrictID")).ToString();
        ddlPurposeName.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PurposeID")).ToString(); 
        ddlTypes.SelectedValue = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TypeID")).ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `DataControlRowState` in the `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GVAllProjects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check if the edit state > 0
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            //do stuff with the row that is being edited
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then the problem is not in the snippet you provided. There is no reference to `AllProjects_Result` or `Projects` in `GVAllProjects_RowDataBound`. The problem is then most likely in the `EditItemTemplate` of the GridView. Something like `Eval("Projects")` that does not exist.

Comment: You are probably using or binding `Projects` in the `EditItemTemplate` somewhere. Remove all `Projects` references or check for spelling errors in what I assume is the dataset "`AllProjects_Result`".